# XSLT transform XML | How to Remove special characters

Tags: xml, xslt

input XML:

```
<Products>
    <Product id="ADEDEWADE0009" name="Akumulator DeWalt XR DCB184-XJ (Li-Ion)" producer="DEW" categoryId="ADE-ADE" warranty="F012M" priceNet="234.00" vat="23" vat_type="zwykły" pkwiu="27.20.23.0" externalWarehouse="N" available="30" date="2018-06-08" onOrder="N" specialOffer="N" smallPallet="N" productIsLarge="N" reported="T" EAN="5035048466933" manufacturerPartNumber="DCB184-XJ" sizeWidth="90" sizeLength="75" sizeHeight="130" weight="672" sizeMeasurementUnit="mm" weightMeasurementUnit="g" dimensionalWeight="175" additionalAvailabilityInfo="" expiryDate="1900-01-01" ETA="" incomingStock="0" mainCategoryTree="Dom, Warsztat i Ogród" categoryTree="Narzędzia - osprzęt" subCategoryTree="Akumulatory">
        <Images>
            <Image url="/Icecat/O2N59732L0C0C1V6o7K4N143m7O7K7A8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/I4B7m9t9K000X1b6w7V471A3H7R737c8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/O9P0t7g7k0k0E1s6H7O4u1R3H7c757V9.jpg" isMain="1" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/I1P2w3a2c0r0N116X7E4P1a3n7l7w7q9.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/T9X096A3D0D0T1d6A7h481i3B7P7A8L0.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/Q1D233T3K020Z10607c421L3N7Z7Q8n1.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
            <Image url="/Icecat/Z2X2z2e5s03031B6G7r4j1Z2W4C9B926.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
        </Images>
        <Multimedia />
        <TechnicalSpecification>
            <Section name="Cechy">
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute name="Kolor produktu">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Name="Czarny" />
                            <Value Name="Żółty" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute name="Wymiary otworu (dł.*szer.*wys.)"
                        <Values>
                            <Value Name="DeWALT" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute name="Napięcie baterii">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Name="18 V" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Name="Litowo-jonowa (Li-Ion)" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
            </Section>
        </TechnicalSpecification>
    </Product>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="first-step-result">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="dynamic-elements" select="$first-step-result//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Image_extra')]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cdata-section-elements" select="$dynamic-elements/node-name()"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="serialize($first-step-result, map { 'method' : 'xml', 'indent': true(), 'cdata-section-elements' : $cdata-section-elements })"/>
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Products">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Product">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:element name="{name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Images/Image"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TechnicalSpecification/Section/Attributes/Attribute"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Image[@isMain='1']">
      <Image_main>
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </Image_main>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Image[@isMain='0']">
      <xsl:element name="{concat('Image_extra_',position())}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,' ()', '___')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value/@Name"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code working very well but I have problem in my structure XML.

issue is related to this part XML code:

```
<Attributes>
                        <Attribute name="Kolor produktu">
                            <Values>
                                <Value Name="Czarny" />
                                <Value Name="Żółty" />
                            </Values>
                        </Attribute>
                        <Attribute name="Kompatybilność z marką">
                            <Values>
                                <Value Name="DeWALT" />
                            </Values>
                        </Attribute>
                        <Attribute name="Napięcie baterii">
                            <Values>
                                <Value Name="18 V" />
                            </Values>
                        </Attribute>
                        <Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii">
                            <Values>
                                <Value Name="Litowo-jonowa (Li-Ion)" />
                            </Values>
                        </Attribute>
                    </Attributes>
```

I try transform this code like:

```
 <Kompatybilność_z_marką>DeWALT</Kompatybilność_z_marką>
```

But currently I cannot transform because this attributes contains most of special characters like:
`<Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii&ć#">`

and program return error with invalid tag name.

1. How to remove all special charasters and Polish characters to always get correct output  like:

   <rodzaj_baterii>

Comment: For the samples as posted I don't get any error. It is not clear which characters from the input create a problem as XML with full Unicode support should probably accept Polish letters the same way as English ones. Anyway, as you use XSLT 2 or 3, you have the powerful `replace` function with support for Unicode categories/classes, so there should hopefully a way to remove characters that don't work, but perhaps only someone with knowledge of the used script (Polish) and the used data and the right output specification can solve that competently.

Comment: Or perhaps the code as used currently works and is UTF-8 encoded text but for whatever reasons when further processing the result of the XSLT somehow a different encoding is used and causing the errors? Try adding e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="serialize($first-step-result, map { 'method' : 'xml', 'omit-xml-declaration': false(), 'indent': true(), 'cdata-section-elements' : $cdata-section-elements })"/>`.

Comment: Your XML shows `<Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii">` but then you say it's `<Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii&ć#">`. If it's the latter, then it's not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT (at least not as XML - with XSLT 3.0 you may be able to load it as unparsed text, replace the invalid characters and then parse it to XML). If it's the former, then there is no error.

Comment: @Martin Honnen  I use oXygen tool. Please see example screen when I try transform https://prnt.sc/PkUzXL4rG9Yw

Comment: with this above code when I remove 3 then working, and I try again transform and another example: https://prnt.sc/ekcE2_NZgplP

Comment: in another example you see: (dł.*szer.*wys.)  and this XML contains such various characters and it is impossible to include them all here.

Comment: Right, but there the problem is not a Polish character, the value starts with a digit and XML names can't start with a digit, they have to start with an Unicode letter. So in the end perhaps it is not a good idea to try to use that data as the base of an element name at all. Or at least it is not clear which strategy to apply which would give a meaningful and working element name; would `<xsl:element name="{replace(@name, '\P{L}+', '')}">` work, which throws out anything not being a letter?

Answer (score 0):

The example

```
<Attribute name="Rodzaj baterii&ć#">
```

contains an unescaped ampersand. That means it is not well-formed XML, which means that you cannot process it with XSLT.

You need to find out where this corrupt XML came from and fix the process that created it.